# Applescript uses wrong python version, how to change?

Tags: python, macos, version, applescript

I recently installed python 2.6.5 over 2.6.1 on OS X. Everything works fine except when I try executing python scripts via the Applescript editor. If I execute the following line I get version 2.6.1:

Applescript:

```
do shell script "python -c \"from sys import version; print version\""
```

But if I execute the similar line in the OS X terminal i get version 2.6.5:

OS X terminal:

```
python -c "from sys import version; print version"
```

What could be wrong? Can this somehow be easily fixed?

Comment: How exactly did you install over? Where is python 2.6.1 and 2.6.5?

Comment: I ment I installed 2.6.5 parallel to 2.6.1 but 2.6.5 is the primary python interpreter...most of the time it seems. I used the OS X installer disk image, never specified where the files should end up.  2.6.1 was preinstalled. I've done the same thing on two different mac's before (both snow leopard) without problem so I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python 2.6.5 installer modifies your `~/.bash_profile` file to put Python 2.6.5's `bin` directory at the start of your `$PATH`, ahead of `/usr/bin` which is where the OS's default Python interpreter lies. That profile is automatically read when you log in via Terminal, but not when using `do shell script`. You either need to specify the full path to the `python` executable you want (probably the best option), or you could have your script read the bash profile beforehand (though be aware that `do shell script` uses `sh`, not `bash`):

```
do shell script ". ${HOME}/.bash_profile; python -c 'import sys; print(sys.version)'"
```

Comment: Both your solution works, I'll settle with one of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I won't recommend overwriting system-installed `python` (or whatever UNIX commands,) because some of the system app might depend on the quirk of a particular version of `python` installed.

It's quite customary these days to install another distinct copy of `python` (or `perl` or `ruby`) in an entirely different path. 
Then you set up the path appropriately in `.profile` etc. in the case of bash so that in the command line `python` you installed will be chosen.

But note that the GUI app inherits the environment variables from the system and don't read `.profile` or whatever. There's a way to change `PATH` environment variable seen by the GUI apps (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html)), but I don't recommend it.

Where did you install your `python` 2.6.5? Say it's in

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Then in your AppleScript code you can just say

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/python  -c ... ."
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Just wish it would work without specifying interpreter, like this for example: do shell script "/Users/Me!/test.py"

Comment: You can put `#!` line at the beginning of the `python` file.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix) . You need to write something like `#!/usr/local/bin/python` at the head. And yes, you need to put the full path there.

Comment: I have specified the correct shebang already :( The problem only occurs when applescript itself chooses python interpreter.

Comment: That's weird. If you have the correct shebang, and the file has the executable bit, do shell script "/path/to/script.py" should just work, invoking the interpreter specified in the shebang.

Answer (score 0):

The mac default install places python in */usr/bin*, the python installer places it in frameworks with sym links in */usr/local/bin*. Just remove the old version in */usr/bin* and create new sym links

```
ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python /usr/bin/python
```